# In 2020 what is the optimal way to train a model in Pytorch on more than one GPU on one computer?

Tags: parallel-processing, neural-network, pytorch, gpu

What are the best practices for training one neural net on more than one GPU on one machine?

I'm a little confused by the different options from `nn.DataParallel` vs putting different layers on different GPUs with `.to('cuda:0') and .to('cuda:1')`. I see in the Pytorch [docs](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html) the latter method the date was 2017. Is there a standard or does it depend on preference or the type of model?

Method 1

```
class ToyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ToyModel, self).__init__()
        self.net1 = torch.nn.Linear(10, 10)
        self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.net2 = torch.nn.Linear(10, 5)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.relu(self.net1(x))
        return self.net2(x)

model = ToyModel().to('cuda')
model = nn.DataParallel(model)
```

Method 2

```
class ToyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ToyModel, self).__init__()
        self.net1 = torch.nn.Linear(10, 10).to('cuda:0')
        self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.net2 = torch.nn.Linear(10, 5).to('cuda:1')

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.relu(self.net1(x.to('cuda:0')))
        return self.net2(x.to('cuda:1'))
```

I'm not sure there aren't more ways Pytorch provides to train on more than one GPU.
Both of these methods seem to cause my system to freeze depending on what model I use them. In Jupyter the cell stays at a [*] and if I don't restart the kernel the screen freezes and I have to do a hard reset. A few tutorials on multi-gpu cause my system to hang and freeze like this.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot fit all the layers of your model on a single GPU, then you can use [model parallel](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/model_parallel_tutorial.html) (that article describes model parallel on a single machine, with `layer0.to('cuda:0')` and `layer1.to('cuda:1')` like you mentioned).

If you *can*, then you can try [distributed data parallel](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html) - each worker will hold its own copy of the entire model (all layers), and will work on a small portion of the data in each batch. DDP is recommended instead of DP, even if you only use a single machine.

Do you have some examples that can reproduce the issues you're having?
Have you tried running your code with tiny inputs, and adding print statements to see whether progress is being made?

Comment: RE: The issues I'm having. My system just freezes up when I use any method of training on more than one GPU using Pytorch. I posted another question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64129118/multi-gpu-training-in-pytorch-causes-my-system-to-freeze). I didn't get to the bottom of it. I think it must be an issue with my system. I think multi-GPU may have worked a few weeks before I plugged a new SSD into a PCIe slot. My PC has a weird setup. Anyways, I'm looking at getting new 30 series cards, maybe two 30 series Titans so I can 10x my training times. I have two 1080tis &use 1

Answer (score 3):

Since you said *2020* and *optimal*, the answer is **definitely** [DDP, Distributed Data Parallel](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/ddp.html). `DataParallel` is much less efficient and is only good for quick-and-easy training in 2020. I wouldn't consider `DataParallel` to be close to optimal. The switch from DP to DDP was painful but was definitely worth it for me.

As of today, the official tutorial on DDP is still a pile of mess in my opinion. I personally went with [this tutorial](https://yangkky.github.io/2019/07/08/distributed-pytorch-tutorial.html).

I will highlight some of the points that had confused me in the learning process. It is essential to get these points, not just to make the code runs, but to make sure it trains **correctly**. There can be subtle mistakes that corrupt training without runtime errors.

1. In DDP, we spawn *one process for each GPU*. If your code starts from `main.py`  and you are using 2 GPUs, imagine someone will call `python main.py --local_rank=0` and  `python main.py --local_rank=1` to spawn two python processes.
2. Each process receives its local rank and the global pool size. Use them to distinguish the processes.
3. Each process initializes its `Dataset` objects independently. They collect their own samples from their own dataloaders. How do we ensure that they don't get the same piece of data point then? Pass a `DistributedSampler` to the dataloader.
4. Each process performs forward, backward, and loss computation independently. They communicate the gradient in lockstep.
5. Warp your model in `nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel`. Then PyTorch will do (4) for you.