# Multi GPU training in Pytorch causes my system to freeze

Tags: machine-learning, parallel-processing, pytorch

When I wrap my model in `nn.DataParallel(model)` and start training my screen freezes and I have to manually restart the computer every time.

I've tried a few variations, like not adding `.to(device)` to every `x` and `y`, but whenever `nn.DataParallel` is used I seem to cause the computer to freeze.

```
import random
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision import models, datasets, transforms

import torch.utils.data

DataLoader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader
random_split = torch.utils.data.random_split

global_rank = 0
MNIST = datasets.MNIST

class MLPClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MLPClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.layer_1 = torch.nn.Linear(28 * 28, 128)
        self.layer_2 = torch.nn.Linear(128, 444)
        self.layer_3 = torch.nn.Linear(444, 333)
        self.layer_4 = torch.nn.Linear(333, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.layer_1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.layer_2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.layer_3(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.layer_4(x)
        return x

# Download data
if global_rank == 0:
    mnist_train = MNIST(os.getcwd(), train=True, download=True)
    mnist_test = MNIST(os.getcwd(), train=False, download=True)

# dist.barrier()

#transforms
transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                             transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))])
mnist_train = MNIST(os.getcwd(), train=True, transform=transform)


# Split dataset
mnist_train, mnist_val = random_split(mnist_train, [55000, 5000])
mnist_test = MNIST(os.getcwd(), train=False, download=True)

# Build dataloaders
mnist_train = DataLoader(mnist_train, batch_size=256)
mnist_val = DataLoader(mnist_val, batch_size=256)
mnist_test = DataLoader(mnist_test, batch_size=256)

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")


model = MLPClassifier()
model = nn.DataParallel(model)
model.to(device)


optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

# Train loop
model.train()
num_epochs = 1
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for train_batch in mnist_train:
        x, y = train_batch
        logits = model(x.to(device))
        loss = F.cross_entropy(logits, y.to(device))
        print('rain loss: ', loss.item())
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # EVAL LOOP
        model.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            val_loss_a = []
            for val_batch in mnist_val:
                x, y = val_batch
                logits = model(x.to(device))
                val_loss = F.cross_entropy(logits, y.to(device))
                val_loss_a.append(val_loss)
            avg_val_loss = torch.stack(val_loss_a).mean()
            model.train()
```

Comment: Have you seen this discussion? I'm not sure if it'll help you, but hope it will. https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dataparallel-freezes/36208/6

Comment: Thank you. I did see that and tried it before. I've looked at a few GitHub 'issues' about it too. One suggested disabling IOMMU. Did that. Still nothing. I wonder if it is just a bad combo of my CPU, GPU driver version, Torch version, motherboard, since it doesn't seem to be a logical error on my part.

Comment: @Renoldus could it be a power supply problem? e.g. not enough wattage for 2 fully-loaded GPUs.

Comment: @hkchengrex Hard to diagnose. Power supply should not be an issue because I have 1000 watt supply and just the two 1080tis and otherwise a regular components. I put an SSD in one of my PCIe slots and I think my problem started then. My OS boots on this new SSD. I could have sworn I got nn.DataParallel to work a few weeks ago before this new SSD, but I think I just kind of ran it once for a few seconds to see if it would work. Hasn't worked for anything since I dried again. I tried Distributed Data Parallel too. No dice. Sometimes when the freeze starts my gpu:1 goes to 100% usage. Weird.

Comment: @Renoldus Is the new SSD close to GPU:1? I had a problem where the SSD will overheat and hang the system, but it was a M.2 SSD directly beneath the GPU.

Comment: It is. I took the side off and felt around the SSD after seeing your comment. Everything feels very cool though the machine had been on for a while. My second SSD that is not in a PCIe slot has a Windows OS on it. I haven't thought to unplug the PCIe SSD and see if I can get Pytorch working on Windows. Don't know if it's possible. Or maybe I could put the Ubuntu SSD (currently in the PCIe slot) into the other slot. I wonder if that would break my system and I'd have to spend three days re-installing everything.